# Why does String == "" return false in Java but not in C#?

Tags: c#, java, string

I have a simple recursive method written in both Java and C#

**Java**

```
public static String reverse(String letter) {
    if (letter == "")
        return "";
    else
        return letter.substring(letter.length() - 1)
                + reverse(letter.substring(0, letter.length() - 1));
}
```

**C#**

```
public static string reverse(string letter)
{
    if (letter == "")
        return "";
    else
        return letter[letter.Length - 1]
                + reverse(letter.Substring(0, letter.Length - 1));
}
```

But the Java version fails at `letter == ""`, it returns false even if the letter is empty. Why does the C# version work while the Java version fails?

Comment: @Douglas: I've reopened the question and wiped the comments. Thanks for your help!

Comment: 3 years later, when I come here again, I feel this question stupid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both C# and Java, the `==` operator checks for reference equality *by default*.

However, in .NET, the `==` operator is overloaded for the `string` type to check for value equality instead:

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return string.Equals(a, b);
}
```

Another factor you need to take into account when using both languages is string interning, which can cause even reference equality to succeed for strings that might appear distinct. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) (for C#):

> The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a particular value only exists once in the system.
>
> For example, if you assign the same literal string to several variables, the runtime retrieves the same reference to the literal string from the intern pool and assigns it to each variable.

String interning is applied across both Java and C#, and typically gives consistent results. For example, both languages evaluate string concatenation at compile-time, meaning that `"a" + "b"` is stored as `"ab"`:

```
"ab" == "a" + "b"                                      // Java: Gives true
object.ReferenceEquals("ab", "a" + "b")                // C#:   Gives true
```

However, when getting a zero-length substring, only C# returns the interned empty string:

```
"" == "abc".substring(0, 0)                            // Java: Gives false
object.ReferenceEquals("", "abc".Substring(0, 0))      // C#:   Gives true
```

Answer (score 5):

Because for objects the operator  `==` test for equality of references. You must always use `equals`

Comment: Which one should I use to check empty string: letter.equals("") or letter.isEmpty() ?

Comment: `isEmpty()` is self describtive, so I would go for it.

Comment: I got it, thanks! So, == in java and c# are different on string, one compares reference, the other compares value. Am I right?

Comment: Make sure you over the `null` case then. Otherwise `letter.anything` will throw a `NullPointerException` (`"something".equals(letter)` is always preferable over `letter.equals("something")` for that reason).

Answer (score 4):

A String is an object.

When you use `==`, you are doing an identity comparison. This means that `a == b` is asking whether `a` and `b` are the same object.

The variable `letter` and the constant object `""` are not the same object, so you get false.

Instead, you should be using:

`letter.equal("")`

This is asking if the `letter` object has a value equal to `""`, which is what you mean to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Several ways to do this:

1. For comparing Strings in Java we have to use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` methods. `... if (letter.equals("")) { ...`
2. Checking the length tells whether or not this String length is 0. `... if (letter.length() == 0) { ...`
3. There is am equivalent for `(letter.length() == 0)` in Java. That is `.isEmpty()` method.

**BTW:**
Don't forgot to `if (letter == null)`.

Comment: Some explanation as to why this is necessary would be useful

Answer (score 2):

In java `==` compares whether two variables contain the same *object*. The constant `""` will probably always be a different instance of String, even though both instances may contain the same string value.

If you want to compare the *contents* of the object then, in the case of String, you can do it like this:

letter.equal("")

Answer (score 1):

In Java,

the `==` operator compares the values in the variables.

So, in case of primitive type variables it will work because the values in the variables are actual values of the primitives.

e.g.

```
 int a = 1;
 int b = 2;

 if(a == b) {
```

In the above it is doing what you think it's doing.

---

But, in case of reference type variables, the values in the variables are the references to the objects that they are pointing to.

So, if you want to do an identity check (i.e. you want to see if two different variables are pointing to the same object) then you have to use `==`. Which will return false if the variables have reference to two different objects (the contents of the objects being same is not relevent).

But, if what you are trying to campare is the contents of the objects then you have to use `equals` method (but you have to make sure that the `equals` method has been implemented properly).

e.g.

```
String a = "a";
String b = new String("a");

if(a == b) { //... identity check (returns false)

//...

if(a.equals(b)) { //... comparing the contents (returns true)
```

Answer (score 0):

'Cause you're comparing references, use [String.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or [String.equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `equals` method like `letter.equals("")` since equality operator (`==`) ultimately compare reference of the object and not the value.

Also, for `C#` a better practice would be to use `string.Empty` instead `""` like

```
if (letter == string.Empty)
```

Answer (score -1):

== works for String objects((look for string pool java in google), but you should (and must) REALLY use .equals().